# Problemas de permissão no diretório do magento. Como redefinir as permissões?

Tags: upload, magento, permissões

Estou com um problema na pasta `/media/tmp/` e `/media/catalog/product/` do magento. Ao tentar fazer upload das imagens dos produtos na criação do produto, a imagem é enviada para o site mas não aparece na listagem de imagens dos produtos conforme mostrado na imagem abaixo.

> Eu sei porque isso acontece mas não sei resolver.

Tanto no diretório temporário quando no diretório definitivo, a imagem recebe a permissão **640** quando é jogada na pasta e deveria receber a permissão **644**. Quando eu uso o `magento-cleanup.php`, tudo volta ao normal porque o script simplesmente redefine todas as permissões de pastas e arquivos existentes.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Abra o seguinte arquivo:
`lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php`
Encontre esta linha:

```
    chmod($destinationFile, 0640);
```

Substitua o 640 por 644, ficando assim:

```
    chmod($destinationFile, 0644);
```

Encontre esta outra linha:

```
 if (!(@is_dir($destinationFolder) || @mkdir($destinationFolder, 0750, true))) {
```

Substitua o 750 por 755, ficando assim:

```
 if (!(@is_dir($destinationFolder) || @mkdir($destinationFolder, 0755, true))) {
```

Agora basta acessar o seu painel administrativo do Magento e fazer o Upload de uma nova imagem para conferir.

> As imagens enviadas anteriormente que não estão aparecendo, devem ter
>   as permissões alteradas manualmente.

Fonte: https://www.secnet.com.br/blog/imagem-do-produto-nao-aparece